# Send data from array of objects to component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

GOAL: Render 3 `SearchItem` components from `locations[0].results[0]` and 3 `SearchItem`  components from `locations[0].results[1]`

I have an array of objects who's data I want to render in my `SearchItem` component:

```js
const locations = [
    {
      results: [
        { name: "Rome, Italy", price: 100, distance: 1299, match: 96 },
        { name: "Beijing, China", price: 200, distance: 3000, match: 93 },
        { name: "California, USA", price: 250, distance: 420, match: 75 },
      ],
    },
    {
      results: [
        { name: "Rome, NY", price: 100, distance: 1299, match: 96 },
        { name: "Spain", price: 200, distance: 3000, match: 93 },
        { name: "California, USA", price: 250, distance: 420, match: 75 },
      ],
    },
  ];
```

And here is how I'm  passing data via props to the component:

```js
  {locations[0].results.map((location, index) => {
            return <SearchItem locations={locations[0].results[index]} />;
          })}
```

Now, when I console log in my `SearchItem` component only ```location[0].results[0] is printing.

Here is my `SearchItem` component:

```js
function SearchItem({ locations }) {
  console.log(locations);
  return (
    <SearchItemsContainer>
     {location.name}
    </SearchItemsContainer>
  );
}
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Try the below code

```
{locations[0].results.map((location) => <SearchItem location={location} />)}
```

```
function SearchItem({ location }) {
  console.log(location);
  return (
    <SearchItemsContainer>
     {location.name}
    </SearchItemsContainer>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
{locations[0].results.map((location, index) => {
            return <SearchItem locations={location}  key={index} />;
})}
```